# Stream audio from server to multiple clients asynchronous

Tags: audio, streaming, client-server

I've a scenario where am having a centralized server which runs on linux and it needs to stream audio and video asynchronously to say 100 clients. The input to the server is received from another server. The question on context is "Is there a way to stream the audio independently to each of the clients?"

Note: 1. Video and Audio is unique for each clients.